# Restrict $wgWhitelistRead by group membership possible?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

Infortunately i have the task to administer the mediawiki of my company and i don't know much about it. My company does not allow extensions for security reasons. The wiki is private, so that only registered users can see the content. Only sysops can create new users. 
I am I have created a group that can only edit and view a single page. The page call is enabled by $wgWhitelistRead. This also allows anonymous users to read the page. Is it possible to create an if query for registered users in localsettings.php, so that only registered users see the website? Or is there a better way for my purpose?

PS: I know that a wiki is not really made for what my company uses it for, but unfortunately the bureaucrats don't want to use anything else out of habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, with your constraints: No, there's no way of doing such thing you ask for.

Longer answer: While it would be possible to use extensions (which you actively said you can not) to achieve what you want, generally spoken, MediaWiki is not built to support such use cases at all. That means, even if you use certain extensions it can result in strange behaviour and the security is not guaranteed, that the pages will always be visible to the people who are allowed to, only.

You can find more documentation about that [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Preventing_access#Restrict_viewing_of_certain_specific_pages).